# Apache Rewrite Rule with Habari Default Rewrites

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2, habari

I've switched my blog from one CMS/Blog System to using Habari which has some default Apache rewrite rules and I'm trying to redirect all the old article URL's from `/articles/article-name` to `/article-name`. Below I've posted what the URL rewrite I'm using and the defaults included with the Habari system, I think it may be a placement issue. Should my rewrites be above theirs?

Habari Default Apache Rwrites:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule . index.php [PT]
RewriteRule ^(system/(classes|handlers|locale|schema|$)) index.php [PT]
```

My URL Rewrite Tacked on to the end of the Habari Rewrite Rules

```
RewriteRule ^/articles/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,PT]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you'll want to insert your rule in a specific place in the order:

```
...
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/articles/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,PT]
RewriteRule . index.php [PT]
...
```

This will allow your old URL to be rewritten, and then Habari can handle the rewritten request.

Comment: Gave you a vote up for correct answer but this is one of the places I tried before and I tried it again still nothing, I can't figure out why it's not working, thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:** I know one answer has already been accepted, but maybe this one will solve your problem:

> Your rule: `RewriteRule ^/articles/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,PT]`

If the rule is inside one .htacces file, it doesn't work because:

> "...Therefore, a Pattern with ^/ never  matches  in per-directory  context..." (Extracted from [Per-directory Rewrites](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule))

When used in .htaccess files, the rule should be:

```
RewriteRule ^articles/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,PT]
```

However, if directory `/articles` doesn't exist, the first rule is used and yours will never be applied as the first one creates a new request.

If that's the case, you have to modify the current code, to:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteBase /

# Add next line if directory "/articles" doesn't exist. 
# If exists, the previous condition "%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d" 
# will exclude it from the rule. 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !/articles [NC]

RewriteRule . index.php [PT]

# Add new rule
RewriteRule ^articles/(.*) /$1 [R=301,PT,NC]

RewriteRule ^(system/(classes|handlers|locale|schema|$)) index.php [PT]
```

The above modifications are also valid for code in the main Apache configuration files, except the rewrite rule should be:

```
RewriteRule ^/articles/(.*) /$1 [R=301,PT,NC]
```

Similar to the rule in your question.

Comment: I very much thank you for your reply but that still isn't functioning correctly for me. I had already figured out that the / before articles needed removed.

Comment: Where is the .htaccess file and what is the error or problem? Make sure the browser's cache is cleared before any test.

Comment: As far as I can tell from testing over at http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/ they should work, tried clearing caches and everything, still no go. Any more ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: A silly one: Did your code work before the modifications? Are there any more rules and, again, what's the error or problem you are facing? Can't say anything if don't know what's the problem.

Comment: Please copy+paste in a comment the complete testing and redirected URLs.

Comment: I believe you are correct the first time through but then as the rules run again, I don't think the `RewriteRule . index.php [PT]` is getting hit the second pass through and I think it should be, correct?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29272/discussion-between-ars265-and-faa)

Answer (score 0):

Description:    Provides a rule-based rewriting engine to rewrite requested URLs on the fly
Status: Extension
Module Identifier:  rewrite_module
Source File:    mod_rewrite.c
Summary
The mod_rewrite module uses a rule-based rewriting engine, based on a PCRE regular-expression parser, to rewrite requested URLs on the fly. By default, mod_rewrite maps a URL to a filesystem path. However, it can also be used to redirect one URL to another URL, or to invoke an internal proxy fetch.

mod_rewrite provides a flexible and powerful way to manipulate URLs using an unlimited number of rules. Each rule can have an unlimited number of attached rule conditions, to allow you to rewrite URL based on server variables, environment variables, HTTP headers, or time stamps.

mod_rewrite operates on the full URL path, including the path-info section. A rewrite rule can be invoked in httpd.conf or in .htaccess. The path generated by a rewrite rule can include a query string, or can lead to internal sub-processing, external request redirection, or internal proxy throughput.

Further details, discussion, and examples, are provided in the detailed mod_rewrite documentation.

Directives
RewriteBase
RewriteCond
RewriteEngine
RewriteMap
RewriteOptions
RewriteRule
Topics
Logging
Comments
top
Logging

mod_rewrite offers detailed logging of its actions at the trace1 to trace8 log levels. The log level can be set specifically for mod_rewrite using the LogLevel directive: Up to level debug, no actions are logged, while trace8 means that practically all actions are logged.

Using a high trace log level for mod_rewrite will slow down your Apache HTTP Server dramatically! Use a log level higher than trace2 only for debugging!
Example

LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3
RewriteLog

Those familiar with earlier versions of mod_rewrite will no doubt be looking for the RewriteLog and RewriteLogLevel directives. This functionality has been completely replaced by the new per-module logging configuration mentioned above.
To get just the mod_rewrite-specific log messages, pipe the log file through grep:
tail -f error_log|fgrep '[rewrite:'